# View All Comments with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm trying to put together a view more comments function. So my original post with the id of comment_streamitem is the original posts id and the comment_id is the comments id. 
I show two comments on the posts then an view all link shows.

I am currently able to get all the comments from the database through $_GET JSON array and it shows as such in Firebug. The comment_list_ID removes the two original comments and removes the view link but doesn't insert the 4 retrieved comments from the database the area where they should insert into its div stays blank.

Could someone look over my code for any possible oversights or errors please?

Thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
$(".view_comments").click(function()
{
var ID = $(this).attr("id");

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "viewmorecommentslink.php?comment_streamitem="+ ID,
success: function(data){
$("#comment_list_"+ID).append('<div id="comment_list_'+data['comment_streamitem']+'"><div class="stream_comment" id="comment_'+data['comment_id']+' style="margin-top:0px; background-color:#000000;"><table width=100%><tr><td valign=top width=30px><img class="stream_profileimage" style="border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;" border=\"0\" src=\"userimages/cropped'+data['comment_poster']+'.jpg\" onerror=this.src=\"userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a><td valign=top align=left>\
<a href="/profile.php?username='+data['username']+'">'+data['first']+' '+ data['middle']+' '+data['last']+'</a> - <abbr class="timeago" title="'+data['comment_datetime']+'">'+data['comment_datetime']+'</abbr><div class="commentholder">'+data['comment_content']+'</div><br/>\<div id="commentactivitycontainer"><a style="cursor:pointer;" onClick=\"deletecomment('+data['comment_id']+',comment_'+data['comment_id']+');\">Delete</a><a id="likecontext_'+data['comment_id']+'" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick=\"likestatuscomment('+data['comment_id']+',this.id);\"><div style="width:80px; position:relative; float:left; left:40px" id="likescommentprint'+data['comment_id']+'">Like</div></a><div style="width:80px; position:relative; float:left; left:40px" id="likescommentprint'+data['comment_id']+'"></div></form>\
<a id="dislikecontext_'+data['comment_id']+'" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick=\"dislikestatuscomment('+data['comment_id']+',this.id);\"><div style="width:90px; position:relative;top:-0px; float:left; left:200px" id="dislikescommentprint'+data['comment_id']+'">Dislike</div></a><div style="width:90px; position:relative; top:-0px; float:left; left:200px" id="dislikescommentprint'+data['comment_id']+'"></div></form></div></div></table></div></div></div></div></table></div></div>');
$("#view"+ID).remove();
$("#comment_list_"+ID).remove();
}
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Viewcommentslink.php

```
<?php
require"include/rawfeeds_load.php";

if(isset($_GET['comment_streamitem'])){
$id=$_GET['comment_streamitem'];

$check = "select comment_id,comment_poster,comment_streamitem,comment_datetime,comment_content FROM streamdata_comments WHERE comment_streamitem='$id' order by comment_id";
$check1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

while($resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($check1))
{
$json['comment_id'] = $resultArr['comment_id'];
$json['comment_poster'] = $resultArr['comment_poster'];
$json['comment_streamitem'] = $resultArr['comment_streamitem'];
$json['comment_datetime'] = $resultArr['comment_datetime'];
$json['comment_content'] = $resultArr['comment_content'];

$user=$resultArr['comment_poster'];
$check2= "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$user'";
$check22 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check2);
$resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($check22);
$json['username'] = $resultArr['username'];
$json['id'] = $resultArr['id'];
$json['first'] = $resultArr['first'];
$json['middle'] = $resultArr['middle'];
$json['last'] = $resultArr['last'];

echo json_encode($json);
}}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console? what does console.log(data); show

Comment: I'm getting the returned data

`{"comment_id":"1687","comment_poster":"33","comment_streamitem":"223","comment_datetime":"2014-08-23 17:24:10","comment_content":"ggg","username":"luce","id":"33","first":"lucy","middle":"","last":"ward"}{"comment_id":"1688","comment_poster":"33","comment_streamitem":"223","comment_datetime":"2014-08-23 17:24:13","comment_content":"hh","username":"luce","id":"33","first":"lucy","middle":"","last":"ward"}`

Comment: Ok, well i expect you are getting errors as well, but you can try adding `data = JSON.parse(data);` at the top of your success function

Comment: Ok i got this SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 205 of the JSON data

Comment: please edit your question to show the content of viewmorecommentslink.php

Comment: Updated as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing the json in a loop, creating a number of json strings. You should only echo a single json string - to do this add to an array in the loop then output that array after the loop:

```
$temp = array();

while($resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($check1))
{

    $json['comment_id'] = $resultArr['comment_id'];
    $json['comment_poster'] = $resultArr['comment_poster'];
    $json['comment_streamitem'] = $resultArr['comment_streamitem'];
    $json['comment_datetime'] = $resultArr['comment_datetime'];
    $json['comment_content'] = $resultArr['comment_content'];

    $user=$resultArr['comment_poster'];
    $check2= "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$user'";
    $check22 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check2);
    $resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($check22);
    $json['username'] = $resultArr['username'];
    $json['id'] = $resultArr['id'];
    $json['first'] = $resultArr['first'];
    $json['middle'] = $resultArr['middle'];
    $json['last'] = $resultArr['last'];


    //echo json_encode($json);

    $temp[]=$json;

}

echo json_encode($temp);
die();
```

Comment: Well its stopped the error but still doesn't put the content into the dic